# Возвращает NaN вместо суммы цифр

Tags: javascript

Скрипт должен сложить цифры из которого состоит число и вывести результат. Но возвращает NaN. Почему?

```
digital_root(16);

function digital_root(n) {
  var result;
    n = n.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i<n.length; i++) {
    n[i] = Number(n[i]);
    result += n[i];
    result = Number(result);
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: `n.length` - у числа нет свойства `length`

Comment: 1) У примитивов нет свойств. Число - примитив. 2) Не используйте обёртки типа `Number`. 3) Логика и консоль говорит о том, что возврата тут нет, да и только `undefined` может быть.

Comment: Обновил.
Использовал n = n.toString() для преображения в строку, чтобы узнать длину.

Comment: стало еще хуже. `n[i] = Number(n[i]);` - это теперь что делает?

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev, у примитивов **нет** свойств.

Comment: Как тогда осуществить алгоритм?

Comment: начать с того, что: `var result = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что строки в javascript - неизменяемы, поэтому нельзя делать так

```
n[i] = Number(n[i]);
```

Вместо этого надо было присвоить значение новой переменной:

```js
digital_root(16);

function digital_root(n) {
  var result = 0,
    nStr = n.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < nStr.length; i++) {
    result += Number(nStr[i]);
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Повышаю до `fn = n => (n + '').split``.reduce((a, n) => a += +n, 0);`.

Comment: @Other, `fn=(n,i=0,r=0)=>{n+='';for(;n[i];i++)r+=+n[i];return r}`

Comment: Однако, мсье, однако... Только у меня всё равно короче решение.

Comment: @Other, в текущем виде мое на два символа короче

Comment: Пробелы у убрать и будет меньше на 11 символов: `fn=n=>(n+'').split``.reduce((a,n)=>a+=+n,0);`.

Comment: @Other, split - Не нужен: `fn=n=>[].reduce.call(n+'',(a,n)=>a+=+n,0);` -2, с фор уже не особо по сокращаешь, return слишком длинный выходит: `fn=(n,i=0,r=0)=>{for(n+='';n[i];r+=+n[i++]);return r}`

Comment: Всё забываю что многое, в т. ч. и строки, обзавелись итераторами.

Comment: @Other, был бы `for` _expression_ а не _statement_ было б интереснее

Comment: Мечты. Попробуйте протолкнуть эту идею в ES2017.